# My Stack Overflow question appears on a different site

Tags: discussion

I posted about this problem a few hours ago on Stack Overflow.

[Prevent to invoke webmethod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098176/prevent-to-invoke-webmethod)

Still unable to find an appropriate answer, I searched on Google. To my surprise I found my  own question here:

http://www.blogosfera.co.uk/2013/04/prevent-to-invoke-webmethod/

Okay – it's not my own property when I post on Stack Overflow, but without my name and Stack Overflow link, how is it possible to post a question on another site? Does Stack Exchange take any action here?

Comment: Seems like that one is new, please report it in the duplicate.

Comment: With proper attribution, that is no problem. All content is licensed with a [CC-BY-SA license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/). However, in this case no attribution is given, so this is not okay. Indeed report it in the duplicated linked in the comments above.